# How to connect to local machine over static global IP with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, connection, ip

I have a program on server. Program is running on some port, like 30000, as example.

I have a client, which is connecting over socket to the server with server's local ip and port (30000). (Both, client and server, are in the same local net).

How can i make the same connection, but over global static (white) server's ip?

The main goal is to establish connection to the 30000 port, from one local net to another, located in some net, under static ip, with `python socket module`.

Comment: I don't know if I understand your problem but as I know you can't do this.